# Accessing an object's method from a List.

Tags: java, list

Below is my code for my DList that takes in objects. It prints out everything fine except for the last print statement. "System.out.println((int)(list.head.next.next.next.item.getItem()));" Why is that? And how to fix it?

```
/* DList1.java */

/**
 *  A DList1 is a mutable doubly-linked list.  (No sentinel, not
 *  circularly linked.)
 */

public class DList1 {

  /**
   *  head references the first node.
   *  tail references the last node.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

  protected DListNode1 head;
  protected DListNode1 tail;
  protected long size;



  public DList1() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;

  }



  public DList1(Object a) {
    head = new DListNode1();
    tail = head;
    head.item = a;
    size = 1;
  }  



  public DList1(Object a, Object b) {
    head = new DListNode1();
    head.item = a;
    tail = new DListNode1();
    tail.item = b;
    head.next = tail;
    tail.prev = head;
    size = 2;
  }

  public void insertFront(Object i) {
    DListNode1 temp = new DListNode1(i);
    if (size == 0) {
      head = temp;
      tail = temp;
    }
    else {
      temp.next = head;
      head.prev = temp;
      head = temp;
    } size++;  
  }

  public void insertEnd(Object i) {
    DListNode1 temp = new DListNode1(i);
    if (size == 0) {
      head = temp;
      tail = temp;
    }
    else {
      tail.next = temp;
    temp.prev = tail;
      tail = temp;    
    } size++;  
  }

  public void removeFront() {
    if (size == 0) {
      return;
    }
    else if (size == 1) {
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      size--;
    }
    else {
      head = head.next;
      head.prev = null;
      size--;
    }
  }


  public String toString() {
    String result = "[  ";
    DListNode1 current = head;
    while (current != null) {
      result = result + current.item + "  ";
      current = current.next;
    }
    return result + "]";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] array = new int[2];
      array[0] = 3;
      array[1] = 4;
      int m = 1;
      String g = "hi";
      String s = "boo";
      String z = "foo";
      DList1 list = new DList1(m);
      tobject jim = new tobject();

      //list.insertFront(g);
      list.insertEnd(s);
      list.insertEnd(g);
      list.insertEnd(jim);
      System.out.println((list.head.item));
      System.out.println((list.head.next.item));
      System.out.println((list.head.next.next.item));
      System.out.println((int)(list.head.next.next.next.item.getItem()));
      System.out.println(list.size);
      //System.out.println((int)(list.head.next.item[0]));// expected 3 but failed
      //System.out.println(((String) list.head.next.item));

  }

}
//////////////
/* DListNode1.java */

/**
 *  A DListNode1 is a node in a DList1 (doubly-linked list).
 */

public class DListNode1{

  /**
   *  item references the item stored in the current node.
   *  prev references the previous node in the DList.
   *  next references the next node in the DList.
   *
   *  DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
   */

  public Object item;
  public DListNode1 prev;
  public DListNode1 next;

  /**
   *  DListNode1() constructor.
   */
  DListNode1() {
    //item = NULL;
    prev = null;
    next = null;
  }

  DListNode1(Object i) {
    item = i;
    prev = null;
    next = null;
      }
    }
////////////
public class tobject {
    private int pai;

    public tobject(){
        pai = 3;
    }
    public int getItem(){
        return pai;
    }
}
```

Comment: Item is an `Object`. It doesn't have any `getItem()` method.

Comment: Your else in `insertend` seems a bit sketchy? It adds `temp` to `tail.next` then sets `temp.prev` to be `tail` and then makes `tail` be `temp` as well?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you first need to cast your returned value to type `tobject` before you can call the special `getItem()` method you defined in `tobject`. Then you can cast the result to `int`, but `println()` is smart enough to print any `Object` or primitive in the "expected" way without casting.

```
System.out.println(((tobject)list.head.next.next.next.item).getItem());
```

But generally trying to have fore-knowledge of what type an item is inside a list is too difficult to manage. This is why [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) can be handy, but it does mean you should try to keep the types of things in a list to the same type or subtype.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you define the `item` as Object in the node? 
Item is an `Object`. It doesn't have any `getItem()` method. Shouldn't your data structure look more like this?:

```
public class DListNode1{
    public tobject item;
    public DListNode1 prev;
    public DListNode1 next;
    ...
    DListNode1(tobject i) {
        item = i;
        prev = null;
        next = null;
    }
}

//You should use uppercase to name class
public class tobject {
    ...
}
```

Then you have to fix all the problems like setting an `int` where you really want to have `tobject`.

Comment: Not all of the items added to the `DList` are of type `tobject` though, so this is invalid